# Scrapy failed to find Xpath that Nokogiri found

Tags: ruby, xpath, scrapy, nokogiri

I am newly working for a website that needs to crawl products from several stores/sites...

I am a bit new to python and scrapy, in which the original code was written, so when testing crawlers and Xpaths, i use Scrapy and also open another console to test using nokogiri (Ruby gem)

in a particular site, i failed to extract some content using scrapy, but I've found that I can get this content, from the same url using same xpath

Here is the code snippet used in both cases:

- Scrapy

  ```
  yield Request(product_url,headers={'User-Agent':'curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3'}, callback=self.parse_item)
  def parse_item(self, response):
      script = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"var ProductViewJSON")]')
      yield {
          'url': response.url,
          'script length': len(script),
          'script': script,
      }
  ```
- it produces following result:

  ```
  {"url": "http://www.pullandbear.com/eg/en/man/accessories/pack-of-3-assorted-bracelets-c29537p100036212.html", "script length": 0, "script": []},
  ```
- Nokogiri

  ```
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  html_data = open('http://www.pullandbear.com/eg/en/man/accessories/pack-of-3-assorted-bracelets-c29537p100036212.html', 'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3').read
  nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::HTML(html_data)
  script = nokogiri_object.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"var ProductViewJSON")]')
  script.length # produces 1
  ```

Can anybody help me to explain that, please note that this scrapy code was running, I've just been reported that it has stopped, and the main problem was the need to add the headers

I hope I was clear enough, thanks for your interest :)

- Edit

  I've tried to parse the url from scrapy shell, using the same User Agent as the spider's request and nokogiri's one, it worked for me, it found the element matching the xpath, but still not running with in the spider...

Comment: When asking, it's important to use correct grammar and spelling. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and the link to Eric Raymond's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for this is the User-Agent you use.

I tried the site with a simple scrapy shell (with the default User-Agent) and I get the following response:

```
>>> response.body
'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;pullandbear&#46;com&#47;eg&#47;en&#47;man&#47;accessories&#47;pack&#45;of&#45;3&#45;assorted&#45;bracelets&#45;c29537p100036212&#46;html" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;3f496768&#46;1453197808&#46;1ef09a53\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

So change your User-Agent in your `Request` (or set it through the settings of scrapy once) and you should be ready to gather your information.

As you can see the server returns an access denied site for User-Agents which are not a browser -- just as your cURL agent.

If I start the shell with the following User-Agent:

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36'
```

and execute your XPath I get following results:

```
>>> response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"var ProductViewJSON")]')
[<Selector xpath='//script[contains(text(),"var ProductViewJSON")]' data=u'<script type="text/javascript">\r\n\tvar Pr'>]
```

Comment: Ok, that was useful, but I tried with the User Agent provided in the original code, that is, the 'curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3' Agent, and it works, just in scrapy shell, not the running spider...

Comment: Ok, I've just tried your User Agent, and it worked... thanks very much